# Expo build fails on react-native-webrtc

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have included react-native-webrtc in my React Native app, and using Expo to build, but expo fails to build on Android. (Works fine in Web and iOS).

`npx expo install react-native-webrtc @config-plugins/react-native-webrtc`

Then using: `npx expo run:android`

I get this:

```
› Building app...
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

> Configure project :app
 ℹ️  Applying gradle plugin 'expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin' (expo-dev-launcher@3.6.9)

> Configure project :expo

Using expo modules
  - expo-constants (15.4.5)
  - expo-dev-client (3.3.11)
  - expo-dev-launcher (3.6.9)
  - expo-dev-menu (4.5.8)
  - expo-file-system (16.0.8)
  - expo-font (11.10.3)
  - expo-json-utils (0.12.3)
  - expo-keep-awake (12.8.2)
  - expo-manifests (0.13.2)
  - expo-modules-core$android-annotation (1.11.12)
  - expo-modules-core (1.11.12)
  - expo-modules-core$android-annotation-processor (1.11.12)


> Task :react-native-webrtc:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-webrtc:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-webrtc:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /Users/conraddewet/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-34/core-for-system-modules.jar.
         > Error while executing process /Users/conraddewet/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-21.0.2/Contents/Home/bin/jlink with arguments {--module-path /Users/conraddewet/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/5c12841351b50cf387568c174a5ace57/transformed/output/temp/jmod --add-modules java.base --output /Users/conraddewet/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/5c12841351b50cf387568c174a5ace57/transformed/output/jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 4s
```

Why is it failing?

I have followed this for the expo stuff: https://github.com/expo/config-plugins/tree/main/packages/react-native-webrtc
and this for the react native webrtc stuff: https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc/blob/master/Documentation/AndroidInstallation.md

Other Info:

```
java -version

openjdk version "21.0.2" 2024-01-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.2+13-58)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.2+13-58, mixed mode, sharing)
```

```
javac -version

javac 21.0.2
```